# Excel: updating cells, restricted by data-validation, when the original source-data changes

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 365, I have two tables; a list of unique names and a list of unique courses. I have a third table to assign a name to a course (many-to-many), using data validation to create a drop-down list for the name and courses.

When I change one of the values in name/course lists, Excel treats the related chosen values in the third table as invalid. Is there a way to automatically update the chosen values when their original source-data changes?

E.g. If I select from "Frod" in the validation drop-down, but then correct "Frod" to "Fred" in the list of names, every instance where I selected "Frod" is marked as invalid (as "Frod" no longer appears in the name list) - but I would like every instance to be updated to "Fred".

As an added issue, the file will be stored in SharePoint, so I was hoping for a solution that runs in online Excel as well as desktop Excel. This isn't a deal-breaker though.

Example file (on OneDrive): https://1drv.ms/x/s!AupeGujEJA0hhmz5boMlzyRxumHP?e=G48lH2

Comment: You may get a better response if you supply dummy data.

Comment: You can try to use Replace feature directly: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-0e304ca5-ecef-4808-b90f-fdb42f892e90